# Docker - Does the container OS need to be same as Host OS

Tags: docker

Can I have a Docker container having Linux OS running on my MAC machine?
As far as my understanding goes, the only thing the Docker and the base OS share is the Kernel.

Comment: *"Can I have a Docker container having Linux OS running on my MAC machine?"* -- absolutely yes!

Answer (score 2):

Docker does share resources with the host os. However the host is always a linus system, in case of mac OS there is a virtualized linux running dockerhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632386/is-docker-a-solution-for-making-application-cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

That is right, docker shares recourses with the host OS. If you want to run an Ubuntu based image on Mac, you will need to run a virtual machine with a linux, which in turn runs the container. Btw. on Mac docker uses docker-machine to run containers, what basically does all that for you.

So all in all docker is not »cross plattform«, if you want to run windows docker containers, you will a windows host, too.

Details: As described [here](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/1.1/installation/system-requirements/), docker requires a linux kernel with a minimum version of 3.10. With that it can use `cgroups` (a kernel feature) to manage the recourses.

So the kernel of the host must have that feature. If not a virtual machine (virtual box, docker-machine) can be used to make that happen on nearly any OS, which is capable to run a VM. But keep in mind, that some features like Port forwarding (`docker run -p 8000:80 …`) will not work with a VM, if you type `http://localhost:8000`, since you need to change that to `http://<ip of vm>:8000`.

Comment: This is outdated. [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) which went public last summer does not use Docker Machine. It uses native hypervisor capabilities built into OSX. And you no longer need to get the IP address of the machine, you can use localhost for containers running on OSX.
You can run Linux base containers on Mac OS, which uses Hypervisor support to do so. You cannot run Windows base images on Mac or Linux however.